# No change redirect url after spring mvc 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Method I want to redirect to the home**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/acceder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String accederPost(Locale locale, Model model, Usuario usuario,HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

**Home Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {        
    model.addAttribute("atributo", new Atributo());
    return "home";
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>   
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>portada.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">  
    <context:annotation-config />  
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.baseapp.web" />      
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />        
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>   
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>    
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>     
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver">
    </bean>         
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
    </bean>     
    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
     </bean>          
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties">  
    </bean>           
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" p:maxActive="${jdbc.maxActive}" p:maxIdle="${jdbc.maxIdle}" p:maxWait="${jdbc.maxWait}" p:logAbandoned="${jdbc.logAbandoned}" 
        p:removeAbandoned="${jdbc.removeAbandoned}" p:removeAbandonedTimeout="${jdbc.removeAbandonedTimeout}">  
    </bean>       
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" p:configLocation="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" >  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>            
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.minPoolSize">${jdbc.maxIdle}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.maxPoolSize">${jdbc.maxActive}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.timeout">${jdbc.removeAbandonedTimeout}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
             <list>
                  <value>/com/responsea/web/model/hbm/A.hbm.xml</value>
              <value>/com/responsea/web/model/hbm/B.hbm.xml</value>  
             </list>
        </property>
    </bean>         
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />       
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">  
    </bean>        
 </beans>
```

The url that is when it comes to the home after running the access url is:

> localhost:8080/proyecto/acceder

Shows no errors on the console or in the logs, arrives at the home but without changing the url did anyone think what might be happening?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using `UrlBasedViewResolver` instead of `InternalResourceViewResolver`?

Comment: No, isn't particular reason to using UrlBasedViewResolver, but not working with UrlBasedViewResolver or InternalResourceViewResolver

Answer (score 2):

Solved, using jquery mobile were activated parameters: pushStateEnabled and ajaxEnabled and took the form submit as reloading ajax content in the same page, the js changing the value of these parameters to false is solved

Answer (score 0):

You are using a GET method (using the url directly), but your controller is using POST.  Try using GET instead of Post,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/acceder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: In the controller i do the login of the user, i sent the form  parameters to the @RequestMapping(value = "/acceder", method = RequestMethod.GET), then the ResquestMethod.GET didn't work for me in this case.